# Incorporating another app into mine

Tags: android

Can I download an alarm clock app and incoperate it onto my app as the alarm clock feature. The idea being that we can save on development and testing.

Personally I don't think it is a good idea but management wants to do it.

What I'd like to know is:

1) Is this even possible ?

2) What would it entail ?

3) What legal implications would there be ?

If it makes a difference the app will not be added to any app store, just packaged with hardware we sell.

Comment: What do you mean by an alarm clock app? Why not use the OS' alarm clock?

Comment: alarm clock was just a simple example, there are other functions they want to use other apps for

Comment: In that case, it really depends on the function you want to have. You can always start an outside app using intents (as long as you know their schema), but starting a random app is not possible, since you don't know said schema.

Comment: 1. No, you can't embed another app in yours. 2. See 1 3. Discuss that with a lawyer

Comment: @Luksprog do you have a link or somthing i can show my boss to back this up ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is this even possible ?

If the "alarm clock app" is open source, you are welcome to use the source code within the terms of its license.

If the "alarm clock app" is not open source, you are welcome to contact the authors of that app to either license its source code or license the binary for distribution on your hardware. In the latter case, you can link to that app (e.g., `startActivity()`), but not "embed" it in any classic sense of the term "embed".

If the "alarm clock app" is not open source, and you do not wish to commercially license it, please develop your own.

Your other questions require an Android programmer and an attorney, respectively. Please hire those individuals, then ask them your questions. The programmer will need to have the specific "alarm clock app" source code (or SDK) to be able to tell you what it will entail.